# What is the best way to level up in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing Clash of Clans for a couple of weeks. I'm in the process of upgrading to Town Hall level 5. What is the best way to level up from here?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your clan should be "Anyone can join" or "Invite Only" really should be based off the focus of the clan. For example, my clan has a 1000 trophy minimum to join. We get typically 1-2 newbies a week, and we'll usually lose 0-1 a week. "Invite Only" is just going to inhibit your clan's growth and put more pressure on the existing clan members.

As for leveling up in Clash of Clans, there's really no best "strategy", but let me detail some tips:

- Level up everything you can before upgrading your Town Hall. The higher your Town Hall level is, the less loot you get. This is due to loot bonuses from attacking players with Town Hall levels than yours, and reduced loot for attacking people with a lower Town Hall level.
- Look up appropriate base layouts for your Town Hall level. There are many guides out there that help you to maximize your defenses at any given Town Hall level. This way you'll lose less resources from being attacked.

  - It's important to note that TH7 is where you really begin to be able to excersize freedom on your layout design, given the additional defensive structures available to you.
- Try to spend resources as they come in. If you have 1,000,000 gold stored up, then you'll lose more when attacked.

  - Not sure what to spend your resources on? Spend any additional income on wall upgrades. I typically time my upgrades and try to aim for certain resource "goals". If I exceed my goals, then I will spend the excess on walls. Though I am fairly active, so it doesn't take long to save up resources for a given upgrade.
- Try to optimize your attacking team to minimize the cost. A few good "more expensive" units along with plenty of cheaper units should yield a higher return than if you need to cover more elixer because you went with all expensive units.
- Save up for that 3rd and 4th builder. I personally couldn't recommend the 5th builder because eventually you'll be struggling to gain enough resources to keep them all occupied.

tl;dr: Attack more often. Upgrade all buildings before Town Hall. Maximize defensive layout.